# How to navigate to a third party component using Android Jetpack's Navigation?

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack

I went through Google's examples for the [Android Jetpack Navigation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/), and it indeed greatly simplifies the navigation between the app's components.

However, I couldn't find any example how to implement navigation to a component provided with a third-party library, like an activity that is supposed to be started with an intent created with a builder provided and should return a result.

Example - in my main activity, I have to redirect to the [Firebase AuthUi](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui?authuser=0) sign-in page if the user is not authenticated:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(...){
  // call super, set contet view, etc.

  if(!isUserAuthenticated()){
    startActivityForResult(
        AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
            .build(),
        RC_SIGN_IN);
  }
}
```

And

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Successfully signed in
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            // ...
        } else {
            // Sign in failed. If response is null the user canceled the
            // sign-in flow using the back button. Otherwise check
            // response.getError().getErrorCode() and handle the error.
            // ...
        }
    }
 }
```

How could I do this using **NavController** instead of directly calling **startActivityForResult**?

Comment: I don't think that external activities can be part of navigation graph, you should keep using it as same way as now.